# Delegate 'Send On Behalf' permission via MS Graph Api

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Ms Graph API and I need to delegate `Send on Behalf` permission for one people to others to achieve like [this](https://kb.intermedia.net/article/2165).

To more clearly is that I need to  delegate `Send on Behalf` permission for other user so that they can send an email on behalf of me by code.

I've searched Graph Api documents but i can not find any api to do that. Any one know how to do this by code. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the EWS to delegate that permission.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641963(v=exchg.150).aspx

But this have some limitation. If you can you can use powershell to grant the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you have already delegated the ability to send on your behalf (based on the documentation you referenced in your question).

The user you delegated to can use Microsoft Graph to send a message on your behalf using the [/me/sendmail](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail) method and specifying your mailbox in `from` property of the message.

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
```

```json
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Message subject",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": "Message body"
        },
        "from": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "you@your-domain.com"
            }
        },
        "toRecipients": [{
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "recipient@recipient-domain.com"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

To the recipient this will show the message as being `from` your email address with the actual user as the `sender`.

Comment: Hi Marc, actually its oposite to your answer. Let me clarify my question. I wonder how to delegate the send on behalf permission by code. I already know how to composed and send an email with send on behalf by graph API

Comment: You cannot enable delegation through Microsoft Graph. It needs to be done via Outlook by the mailbox owner or via Exchange by an administrator.

Comment: Thanks @Marc for the answer.I wonder is there anyway to enable delegation by code.
 I've found this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx . But seems it have functionality like Graph API. Anyway to achieve that by code

Comment: EWS is the legacy Exchange API set and it does have some functionality not yet found in Microsoft Graph. If you're building for internal use it would be reasonable to leverage EWS.

Comment: Thank @MarcLaFleur it solved my bug. But if you don't set "from" it will take the correct address automtically. That worked for me, too.